# the least steps to remove all pebbles on table

Tags: combinatorics

On the table there are 100 bags of pebbles that contain 1, 2, 3, 4, ...., 100 pebbles respectively. In one step you are allowed to reduce the number of pebbles of any number of the bags as long as you take the same number of pebbles from each bag you selected. What is the least number of steps you can take all the pebbles off the table?

Comment: Please don't forget to "accept" the best answer to be a good M.SE citizen.

Answer (score 1):

Write $X_n$ the minimum number of steps required to clear the table if the set of number of pebbles in the bags is $\{1,...,n\}$ (so two or more bags can contain the same number $k \le n$ of pebbles ; they will be cleared at the same time under any optimal strategy anyway).

If you take $m \le n$ pebbles off each bag with more than $m$ pebbles (I'm assuming any optimal strategy would take off as many pebbles as possible at each round but that intuition should be verified), you're left with bags containing between $1$ and $\max (m-1, n-m)$ pebbles (again several bags may contain the same number of p.) and clearing this new table should take $X_{\max (m-1, n-m)}$ steps.

So $\displaystyle X_n = 1+ \min_{1 \le m \le n} X_{\max (m-1, n-m)}$. Given that $X_n$ is increasing (it has to be), the best cut-off $m$ should always be $m=\lceil \frac{n-1}{2} \rceil$ (I hope I got my floor/ceil right), so $X_n = 1 + X_{\lceil \frac{n-1}{2} \rceil}$.

So $X_{100} = 1 + X_{50} = 2 + X_{25} =$ ... $= 5 + X_3 = 6 + X_1 = 7$.

Remove, in order, 50, 25, 12, 6, 3, 1 and 1.

**Edit**

As indicated by @Pratik_Soni, the closed formula is $X_n = \lceil \log_2 (n+1) \rceil$.

Comment: There’s actually considerable freedom in choosing the cut. You can use $\left\lfloor\frac{n}2\right\rfloor$, for instance, but you can also use $2^{\lfloor\lg n\rfloor}$, the highest power of $2$ less than or equal to $n$. (Here $\lg$ is the binary logarithm.)

Comment: Agreed, maybe I wasn't clear enough when I proposed my cut. This is due to the fact that, given that $X_n$ is constant over long ($2^k$) intervals, the $\min X_{\max}$ expression can correspond to different values of $m$. "The best cut-off $m$ ..." should be replaced by "An optimal cutoff $m$ ..."

Answer (score 0):

Seven steps. Take 64 pebbles from each bag containing at least that much. Repeat for 32, 16, 8, 4,2 and 1.